# Undefined JSON usage in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, chatbot

I'm having some problem understanding the syntax of this python code. The code in question is a simple Telegram chatbot, it works by pulling updates from an https gate.

```
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)

def get_url(url):
    response = mechanize.urlopen(url)
    content = response.read()
    return content

def get_json_from_url(url):
    content = get_url(url)
    js = json.loads(content)
    return js

def get_updates(offset=None):
    url = URL + "getUpdates"
    if offset:
        url += "?offset={}".format(offset)
    js = get_json_from_url(url)
    return js

def get_last_update_id(updates):
    update_ids = []
    for update in updates["result"]:
        update_ids.append(int(update["update_id"]))
    return max(update_ids)

def echo_all(updates):
    for update in updates["result"]:
        text = update["message"]["text"]
        chat = update["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        send_message(text, chat)

def get_last_chat_id_and_text(updates):
    num_updates = len(updates["result"])
    last_update = num_updates - 1
    text = updates["result"][last_update]["message"]["text"]
    chat_id = updates["result"][last_update]["message"]["chat"]["id"]
    return (text, chat_id)
```

As far as I can understand the usefulness of JSON in this case is pretty much none, since mechanize returns a UTF-8 str.
But, upon running

```
def main():
    last_update_id = None
    while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_update_id)
        if len(updates["result"]) > 0:
            last_update_id = get_last_update_id(updates) + 1
            #echo_all(updates)
            send_stdmessage(updates)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PreAlpha.py", line 70, in <module>
main()
File "PreAlpha.py", line 62, in main
if len(updates["result"]) > 0:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Whereas the code runs perfectly if I mantain that code section untouched and keep the JSON.

EDIT: This is an example from the data which the bot would be pulling from:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":130999147,"message":
{"message_id":24,"from":
{"id":346850522,"first_name":"XXX","last_name":"XXX"},"chat":
{"id":346850522,"first_name":"XXX","last_name":"XXX",
"type":"private"},"date":1489950868,"text":"Hello"}}]}
```

Comment: Please fix formatting

Comment: It's fixed, thanks for noting.

Comment: Is the code complete? Where's URL defined?

Anyhow, the type of updates seems to be None. Therefore using the __getitem__ -> []  results in an exception?

Comment: Code is now completed, and also added an example of the pull data.

Comment: are you sure you receive correct response each time you make a request?

Comment: how does the response look like when it raises an `Exception`?

Comment: Also, as I stated the code runs without a problem, it's only when the JSON is removed that it puts out the error message.

Comment: you have to check what is happening inside `get_json_from_url`

Comment: Thanks for your replies @mic4ael, as it says on the Python's JSON page, the command json.loads  _"Deserializes a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document to a Python object using a conversion table."_ So I can't understand it's purpose since mechanize.read() returns a str.

Comment: i don't get it, `mechanize.read()` returns a `str` object with `JSON` e.g. '{"updates": []}' and then you have to convert it to a Python object using `json.loads`

Comment: Thanks again for your answer @mic4ael I don't know why but I assumed that the string outputed by `mechanize.read` would be python readable.

Comment: if that is a JSON valid object then you need to convert it to a `dict` using `json.loads`

Answer (score 0):

As @mic4ael pointed out, the command: `mechanize.read()` returns a `str` object with `JSON` e.g. '{"updates": []}' and then it must be converted to a Python object(`dict`) using `json.loads`
I was wrong to believe that the `mechanize.read()' data would be a python object.